# Woocommerce simple product attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi everyone I want to ask if someone know how to make the attribute from text to be shown as simple product.

For example if I have a t-shirt in a simple product and I put some attributes like size: M,L,S and by default they are shown as text and you can not select any of them and not as radio buttons or as drop down list is it possible to make them show as drop down list or radio buttons without making the product as Variable product?

Comment: No.  That by definition is no longer a simple product.  While you may be able to make it show in a drop-down, what then? The system won't handle the selection properly, because you've told it it's a "simple" product, by are trying to use variations....

Comment: Alternatively you could create a single product for each size and then show them all as a grouped product.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :D